# lisp expression evaluator need help in find out how to return LispExpressionException, and LispExpressionEvaluatorException

Tags: java, exception, methods, try-catch, evaluation

What i need help on is being able to print out LispExpressionEvaluatorException and LispExpressionException. i tried adding a catch block to evaluate method but it does not seem to be working. i am not sure where i am going wrong the other test are working but only last 3 questions seem to be errors. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    package PJ2;
import java.util.*;
public class LispExpressionEvaluator extends LispExpressionEvaluatorException
{
    // Current input Lisp expression
    private String currentExpression;

    // Main expression stack, see algorithm in evaluate()
    private Stack<Object> inputExprStack;
    private Stack<Double> evaluationStack;
    public LispExpressionEvaluator() {
         currentExpression = "";
         inputExprStack = new Stack<Object>();
         evaluationStack = new Stack<Double>();
        //Stack<Object> inputExprStack = new Stack<Object>();
        //Stack <Double> newEvaluationStack = new Stack<Double>();
    }
    public LispExpressionEvaluator(String inputExpression) {
        if(inputExpression == null) {
            throw new LispExpressionEvaluatorException();
        }
        currentExpression = inputExpression;
        inputExprStack = new Stack<Object>();
        evaluationStack = new Stack<Double>();
    }
    public void reset(String inputExpression){
        if(inputExpression == null) {
            throw new LispExpressionEvaluatorException();}
        currentExpression = inputExpression;
        //not pop
        inputExprStack.clear();
        evaluationStack.clear();
    }
    // This function evaluates current operator with its operands
    // See complete algorithm in evaluate()
    //
    // Main Steps:
    // Pop operands from allTokensStack and push them onto
    // currentOperandsStack until you find an operator
    // Apply the operator to the operands on currentOperandsStack
    // Push the result into allTokensStack
    private void solveCurrentParenthesisOperation() {


        boolean isNumber = true;
        double endResult = 0;
        if(inputExprStack == null) {
            throw new LispExpressionEvaluatorException();}
        String click = "";
        while (isNumber) {
            if (!inputExprStack.empty()) {
                click = String.valueOf(inputExprStack.pop());
            } else {
                isNumber = false;
                break;
            }
            try {
                Double number = Double.parseDouble(click);
                evaluationStack.push(number);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                isNumber = false;
            }
        }
        if (evaluationStack.size() == 0)
            return;
        switch (click) {
            case "+":
                endResult = evaluationStack.pop();
                while (!evaluationStack.empty()){
                    endResult +=evaluationStack.pop();
                }
            break;
            case "-":
                endResult = evaluationStack.pop();
                if(evaluationStack.size() == 0){
                    endResult = -endResult;
                }
                while (!evaluationStack.empty()){
                    endResult -=evaluationStack.pop();
                }

                break;
            case "*":
                endResult = evaluationStack.pop();
                while (!evaluationStack.empty()){
                    endResult *=evaluationStack.pop();
                }
                break;
            case "/":
                endResult = evaluationStack.pop();
                if(evaluationStack.size() == 0 && endResult != 0){
                    endResult = 1.0/endResult;
                }
                while (!evaluationStack.empty()){
                    endResult /=evaluationStack.pop();
                }
                break;

                default:
                endResult = evaluationStack.pop();
                break;
        }


        inputExprStack.push(endResult);
        System.out.println(endResult + " line 165");
    }
    /**
     * This funtion evaluates current Lisp expression in currentExpression
     * It return result of the expression
     *
     * The algorithm:
     *
     * Step 1 Scan the tokens in the string.
     * Step 2 If you see an operand, push operand object onto the allTokensStack
     * Step 3 If you see "(", next token should be an operator
     * Step 4 If you see an operator, push operator object onto the allTokensStack
     * Step 5 If you see ")" // steps in solveCurrentParenthesisOperation() :
     * Step 6 Pop operands and push them onto currentOperandsStack
     * until you find an operator
     * Step 7 Apply the operator to the operands on currentOperandsStack
     * Step 8 Push the result into allTokensStack
     * Step 9 If you run out of tokens, the value on the top of allTokensStack is
     * the result of the expression.
     */
    public double evaluate() {
            // use scanner to tokenize currentExpression

            Scanner currentExpressionScanner = new Scanner(currentExpression);
            currentExpressionScanner = currentExpressionScanner.useDelimiter("\\s*");
            //inputExprStack.push('(');
            if (inputExprStack == null) {
                throw new LispExpressionEvaluatorException();
            }
            while (currentExpressionScanner.hasNext()) {
                if (currentExpressionScanner.hasNextInt()) {
                    String dataString = currentExpressionScanner.findInLine("\\d+");
                    inputExprStack.push(Double.parseDouble(dataString));
                } else {
                    // Get next token, only one char in string token
                    String aToken = currentExpressionScanner.next();
                    char item = aToken.charAt(0);

                    switch (item) {
                        case '(':
                            break;
                        case '+':
                            inputExprStack.push('+');
                            break;
                        case '-':
                            inputExprStack.push('-');
                            break;
                        case '*':
                            inputExprStack.push('*');
                            break;
                        case '/':
                            inputExprStack.push('/');
                            break;
                        case ')':
                            solveCurrentParenthesisOperation();
                            break;
                        default: // error
                            throw new LispExpressionEvaluator(item + " is not a legal expression operator");
                    } // end switch
                } // end else
            } // end while
            // Push a ')' onto the inputExprStack to balance the '('
            //inputExprStack.push(')');

            // process remaining operators in inputExprStack

            return Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(inputExprStack.pop()));

        }




    //=====================================================================
    // DO NOT MODIFY ANY STATEMENTS BELOW
    //=====================================================================

    
    // This static method is used by main() only
    private static void evaluateExprTest(String s, LispExpressionEvaluator expr, String expect)
    {
        Double result;
        System.out.println("Expression " + s);
        System.out.printf("Expected result : %s\n", expect);
    expr.reset(s);
        try {
           result = expr.evaluate();
           System.out.printf("Evaluated result : %.2f\n", result);
        }
        catch (LispExpressionEvaluatorException e) {
            System.out.println("Evaluated result :"+e);
        }
        
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
    }

    // define few test cases, exception may happen
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        LispExpressionEvaluator expr= new LispExpressionEvaluator();
        String test1 = "(+ (- 6) (* 2 3 4) (/ (+ 3) (* 1) (- 2 3 1)) (+ 0))";
        String test2 = "(+ (- 632) (* 21 3 4) (/ (+ 32) (* 1) (- 21 3 1)) (+ 0))";
        String test3 = "(+ (/ 2) (* 2) (/ (+ 1) (+ 1) (- 2 1 )) (/ 1))";
        String test4 = "(+ (/2)(+ 1))";
        String test5 = "(+ (/2 3 0))";
        String test6 = "(+ (/ 2) (* 2) (/ (+ 1) (+ 3) (- 2 1 ))))";
        String test7 = "(+ (*))";
        String test8 = "(+ (- 6) (* 2 3 4) (/ (+ 3) (* 1) (- 2 3 1)) (+ ))";

    evaluateExprTest(test1, expr, "16.50");
    evaluateExprTest(test2, expr, "-378.12");
    evaluateExprTest(test3, expr, "4.50");
    evaluateExprTest(test4, expr, "1.50");
    evaluateExprTest(test5, expr, "Infinity or LispExpressionEvaluatorException");
    evaluateExprTest(test6, expr, "LispExpressionEvaluatorException");
    evaluateExprTest(test7, expr, "LispExpressionException");
    evaluateExprTest(test8, expr, "LispExpressionException");
    }
}
```

this is the Exception method.

```
package PJ2;

public class LispExpressionEvaluatorException extends RuntimeException
{
    public LispExpressionEvaluatorException()
    {
    this("");
    }

    public LispExpressionEvaluatorException(String errorMsg) 
    {
    super(errorMsg);
    }

}
```

while this is the porject.iml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Comment: A structure where an 'evaluator' extends an exception thrown by the evaluator is broken to start with.  In what sense is the evaluator an object to be thrown?

Comment: @undefinedsymbol going to be honest i am not sure an i thought that was the best course of action. i have no clue what to do here i have been stuck for a long time on just this.